# Simulate numpy.cumsum at the deepest level of a JaggedArray

Tags: python, awkward-array

I have a singe level nested array, and I'd like to calculate the running sum at the deepest level:

```
<JaggedArray [[0.8143442176354316 0.18565578236456845] [1.0] [0.8029232081440607 0.1970767918559393] ... [0.42036116755776154 0.5796388324422386] [0.18512572262194366 0.31914669745950724 0.13598232751162054 0.3597452524069286] [0.34350475143310905 0.19023361856972956 0.4662616299971615]] at 0x7f8969e32af0>
```

after doing something like `numpy.cumsum(jagged_array)` I'd like to have:

```
[[0.8143442176354316 1.0] [1.0] [0.8029232081440607 1.0] ...
```

In short - the running sum at the deepest level (which is restarted with each new "event").

I'm using `awkard0`, and the documentation says that broadcast is run at the deepest level, however, I get an error when I tried just handing a `JaggedArray` directly to `numpy.cumsum`: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)`

The dataset is large - I'd like to stay within the awkward system - so avoid python loops in processing these.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're just trying to call np.cumsum on each of the lists in your larger list.  Let me know if I'm misunderstanding your intention.

In that case

```
result = [np.cumsum(one_list) for one_list in jagged_array]
```

Comment: Yes - I am! This is exactly right - however, what you have there runs the loop at the python level - and I have a few billion "events" to go through, so I was hoping for something deeper in awkward (perhaps this means numba?). Also the result is a python list, as opposed to an awkward one, though it is easy to change it back. I will update my questions.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "high-level" way to do this, a way that is independent of knowledge of the array's layout, but I can walk you through this.

#### Awkward 0.x (obsolete)

Assuming that you have a simple jagged array,

```py
>>> import awkward0
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = awkward0.fromiter([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [], [4.4, 5.5]])
>>> array.layout
 layout 
[    ()] JaggedArray(starts=layout[0], stops=layout[1], content=layout[2])
[     0]   ndarray(shape=3, dtype=dtype('int64'))
[     1]   ndarray(shape=3, dtype=dtype('int64'))
[     2]   ndarray(shape=5, dtype=dtype('float64'))
```

You can apply the cumulative sum to the `content`:

```py
>>> np.cumsum(array.content)
array([ 1.1,  3.3,  6.6, 11. , 16.5])
```

and wrap that up as a new jagged array:

```py
>>> scan = awkward0.JaggedArray.fromoffsets(array.offsets, np.cumsum(array.content))
>>> scan
<JaggedArray [[1.1 3.3000000000000003 6.6] [] [11.0 16.5]] at 0x7f0621a826a0>
```

#### Awkward 1.x

The `offsets` and `content` structure that we directly manipulated in Awkward 0.x are now hidden in a "layout" to distinguish between high-level operations (which don't require knowledge of the exact layout) and low-level operations (which do). This problem doesn't have a high-level solution, and the low-level way is like the above, but it involves extra wrapping and unwrapping.

```py
>>> import awkward as ak
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = ak.Array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [], [4.4, 5.5]])
>>> array
<Array [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [], [4.4, 5.5]] type='3 * var * float64'>
>>> layout = array.layout
>>> layout
<ListOffsetArray64>
    <offsets><Index64 i="[0 3 3 5]" offset="0" length="4" at="0x55737ef6f880"/></offsets>
    <content><NumpyArray format="d" shape="5" data="1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5" at="0x55737ef71890"/></content>
</ListOffsetArray64>
```

As before, you can do a cumulative sum on the `content`:

```py
>>> np.cumsum(layout.content)
array([ 1.1,  3.3,  6.6, 11. , 16.5])
```

Here's the structure of how it gets wrapped up:

```py
>>> scan = ak.Array(
...     ak.layout.ListOffsetArray64(
...         layout.offsets,
...         ak.layout.NumpyArray(
...             np.cumsum(layout.content)
...         )
...     )
... )
...
>>> scan
<Array [[1.1, 3.3, 6.6], [], [11, 16.5]] type='3 * var * float64'>
```

#### What if you want the scan per-list?

If you want a solution similar to Frank Yellin's, in which each scan starts new in each list, the fact that we did one `np.cumsum` on the `content` is a problem. In concrete terms, we have the third list starting with `11`, instead of `4.4`.

A vectorized way to do that is to subtract the first `scan` element of each list from the whole list and add the first `array` element back in. In both Awkward 0.x and 1.x, this can be done with slices like `array[:, 0]` and broadcasting, but empty lists (if you have them) are going to be a problem. Awkward 1.x has enough alternatives to work around that:

```py
>>> ak.firsts(scan)
<Array [1.1, None, 11] type='3 * ?float64'>

>>> scan - ak.firsts(scan)
<Array [[0, 2.2, 5.5], None, [0, 5.5]] type='3 * option[var * float64]'>

>>> scan - ak.firsts(scan) + ak.firsts(array)
<Array [[1.1, 3.3, 6.6], None, [4.4, 9.9]] type='3 * option[var * float64]'>

>>> ak.fill_none(scan - ak.firsts(scan) + ak.firsts(array), [])
<Array [[1.1, 3.3, 6.6], [], [4.4, 9.9]] type='3 * var * float64'>
```

Most of these don't have equivalents in Awkward 0.x.